# Is there a way to pass on a value between GitHub workflow runs?

Tags: github, github-actions

You can share outputs between steps and jobs within the same workflow run, but what about passing information between workflow runs?

For example, I'd like to know the date of the last successful pipeline run, so a global repo variable `LAST_RUN=2023_12_21` would be incremented after every workflow run.

I have found some marketplace actions that update global repo secrets, but these require GitHub tokens. I would imagine there is a simpler way to do this, so I feel like I am missing something here.

Cheers

Comment: You can share inputs using a payload when using dispatch events between workflows ([workflow_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) or [repository_dispatch](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch)) using the Github API: [Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event)